# change a link anchor from a RTE link (CK Editor)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i want to change the anchor from a link set in RTE from #cuid to #title-of-contentelement.

How can i do this?

In the RTE configuration (i use CK Editor) or with a typolink handler or hook?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is still valid:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.postUserFunc = Vendor\Extension\UserFunc\Class->method
```

to modify links before output.

You'll have to fetch the right record (with the help of the original `#c<uid>` value) and replace `c<uid>` with `<title-of-ce>`.